# Serviço Windows para após Exception

Tags: c#, exceção, services

Existe alguma forma de fazer com que um serviço Windows criado em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) não dê `Stop()` após uma `Exception`?

O serviço foi criado com um `timer`, que irá ser executado a cada 1 hora, porém houve um erro na execução e retornou uma `exception`, até ai tudo certo, o problema é que quando virou a hora, o `timer` não deu start.

Precisa fazer algum tratamento específico no `Catch`?

O trecho abaixo é chamado quando o `Timer` é executado.

> o **timerImportacao** é outro Timer

```
private void ExecutarServico()
{
    timerImportacao.Enabled = false;
    CarregarConfiguracoesServico();
    CadastroBusiness biz = new CadastroBusiness();
    try
    {
        if (GeraArquivosExportacao())
        {
            AlertaBusiness.RegistrarLogEventViewer("FEPWeb - Iniciando processo de Exportação.");

            ServicoFepWeb sfw = new ServicoFepWeb();
            sfw.UriInput = uriInput; sfw.DirInput = operServico.CaminhoSaida; sfw.UserCred = userCred; sfw.PassCred = passCred;
            biz.GerarDocumentoFepWeb(operServico.CaminhoSaida);
            sfw.SendFiles();

            if (biz.RetornoFepWeb.Count != 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (string str in biz.RetornoFepWeb.ToArray())
                    sb.Append(str + Environment.NewLine);
                biz.EnviarAlertaFepWebErro("Exportação FEPWeb.", MensagemBusiness.RetornaMensagens("Exportar_FepWeb_Aviso") + Environment.NewLine + sb.ToString(), operServico.DestinatarioMail);
            }
            AlertaBusiness.RegistrarLogEventViewer("Processo de Exportação FEPWeb, concluido com sucesso.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AlertaBusiness.RegistrarLogEventViewer(MensagemBusiness.RetornaMensagens("Exportar_FepWeb_ERR") + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : String.Empty), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        biz.EnviarAlertaFepWebErro("Exportação FEPWeb.", MensagemBusiness.RetornaMensagens("Exportar_FepWeb_ERR") + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : String.Empty), operServico.DestinatarioMail);
    }
    finally
    {
        timerImportacao.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Será que não reiniciou porque ainda estava rodando? Tenho um serviço, com `Topshelf`que não para após exception. Fiquei curioso como fica esse serviço com `Timer`, se o serviço para, como o `Timer` vai disparar já que faz parte do serviço?

Comment: Fiz o tratameto de exception com Throw new Exception(), retornando a falha até o método inicial, assim pego o erro desde o primeiro ponto. Neste caso, a execução naquele momento é interrompida, porem não é retomada no novo ciclo

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar um `try {}` dentro do seu `catch`, o erro pode estar sendo causado por lá.

```
private void ExecutarServico()
{
    timerImportacao.Enabled = false;
    CarregarConfiguracoesServico();
    CadastroBusiness biz = new CadastroBusiness();
    try
    {
        if (GeraArquivosExportacao())
        {
            AlertaBusiness.RegistrarLogEventViewer("FEPWeb - Iniciando processo de Exportação.");

            ServicoFepWeb sfw = new ServicoFepWeb();
            sfw.UriInput = uriInput; sfw.DirInput = operServico.CaminhoSaida; sfw.UserCred = userCred; sfw.PassCred = passCred;
            biz.GerarDocumentoFepWeb(operServico.CaminhoSaida);
            sfw.SendFiles();

            if (biz.RetornoFepWeb.Count != 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (string str in biz.RetornoFepWeb.ToArray())
                    sb.Append(str + Environment.NewLine);
                biz.EnviarAlertaFepWebErro("Exportação FEPWeb.", MensagemBusiness.RetornaMensagens("Exportar_FepWeb_Aviso") + Environment.NewLine + sb.ToString(), operServico.DestinatarioMail);
            }
            AlertaBusiness.RegistrarLogEventViewer("Processo de Exportação FEPWeb, concluido com sucesso.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try {
            AlertaBusiness.RegistrarLogEventViewer(MensagemBusiness.RetornaMensagens("Exportar_FepWeb_ERR") + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : String.Empty), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        biz.EnviarAlertaFepWebErro("Exportação FEPWeb.", MensagemBusiness.RetornaMensagens("Exportar_FepWeb_ERR") + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : String.Empty), operServico.DestinatarioMail);
        } catch {
            ;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        timerImportacao.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```